# nvd3 tool tip with HTML link?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

How can I customize the tool tip to create a link on it?
Obviously, this link should be clickable. I have already done something like

```
  chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d){
          var html = '<h3>' + d.value + '</h3>' +
          ' <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">LINK</a>'+ d.point.x;
          return html;
        });
```

But nothing, I cannot click on the link. Also, I am struggling with the position of the tool tip because I don't know how to fixed that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would seem nvd3 sets `pointer-events: none` in the CSS for the tooltips, which disables link events. You could try overriding this property for the .nvtooltip class or add your own, i.e.

```
chart.tooltip.classes('myclass');

.nvtooltip.myclass {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

And you can use `chart.tooltip.position({ top: 100, left: 100 })();` to position the tooltip wherever you want.